# how to check whether two ts.Types are assignable or not?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I have a use case where i want to check whether two `ts.Type`s are assignable or not ?

```
   class Sample1 {
     updateObj: Type1    
  }
   class Sample 2 {
    field1:Type2
  }
  tn1 = typeNode of updateObj 
  tn2 = typeNode of field1
  const t1 = typeChecker.getTypeFromTypeNode(tn1);
  const t2 = typeChecker.getTypeFromTypeNode(tn2);
   isTwoTypesAssignable(t1,t2)
```

how can i achieve this using typescript compiler api ..

Comment: By assignable, do you mean that you can do `t1 = t2`? What is `typeChecket`? (did you misspell it?) What is `tn1` and `tn2`?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, updated post , i want to know in compile time whether `Type1` and `Type2` assignable or not ..

Comment: assignable to each other? Have identical interfaces?

Comment: See the linked to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44888163/using-the-typescript-type-checker-to-see-if-two-types-are-assignable). Then please go upvote this [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9879). Also, note there is an internal `isTypeAssignableTo` method on the type checker.